# A games console with the verb "play"

Tags: prepositions

> Would you like to play on a games console?
>
> Would you like to play a games console?

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: The console is the instrument: the means, not the ends. So you don't "play the console", you "play on the console". Similar to how you "play football" (ends) but "play on a football field" (means). Ancillary comment: no one says "games console"; in idiomatic English, you'd simply refer to it as a "console", but if you're committed to getting "game" in there somewhere, you'd say "game console", or, even more likely, "gaming console". But not "games console". Long story short: "You wanna play on the console?".

Comment: What @Dan said. Prepositionless *to play a games console* isn't quite as weird as, say, *to play a card table*, or *write a typewriter,* but it's straying into that general area.

Comment: @DanBron: I don't think there's anything odd about "games console", at least in BrE ( https://www.standard.co.uk/stayingin/tech-gaming/xbox-one-x-playstation-4-or-nintendo-switch-which-games-console-should-you-buy-a3688366.html ; https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/gaming/886141/Nintendo-Switch-games-console-Sony-PS4-sales ).

Comment: I agree that we say "play on the console", not "play the console", but whether this is because the console is "the instrument" is another matter.  That might just be a rationalisation.  After all, a guitar or a piano is also an instrument, yet we "play the piano", "play the guitar", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Either "play on a game console", or "play a console game" works.

In the latter version, "console" becomes an adjective describing "game".